# Why is my ajax call rendering a blank page? (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to make an ajax call that either opts a user in or out of receiving emails. When the user clicks the button to do this I don't want the page to reload, I only want to send a message to the server that the user is opting in or out of receiving emails.

JS:

```
opt: function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
    type : 'PUT',
    url  : $this.attr('href'),
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(html) {
      $this.addClass('active');
    }
  }); 
}
```

The opt action in the user controller:

```
def opt
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.no_emails == false
    @user.no_emails = true
    @user.save
  else
    @user.no_emails = false
    @user.save
  end
  render :nothing => true, :status => 200
end
```

When I click the button that calls the function all it does is bring me to a blank page, I believe the `render :nothing => true, :status => 200` part is what is causing the issue but I am not sure.

Comment: As an aside, `@user.toggle(:no_emails).save` is well suited to replace your conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right. `render :nothing => true` renders nothing at all. If you want you can do `redirect_to :back` and that will take the user back to the last visited page.

**EDIT**

Try adding `:remote => true` to your button.

Comment: I don't want the page to reload at all, that is the purpose of the ajax call.

Comment: Oh ok. Try adding `:remote => true` to your button.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when this happens to me it's because there's a javascript error on the page that is preventing `event.preventDefault();` from being called.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `:remote => true` to the link_to made it work.